# Django: find foreign key by class

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a bunch of Django models with a foreign key to an object of class Foo. They use different names for the foreign key -- i.e. it isn't always `foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)`; it could be `bar = models.ForeignKey(Foo)`. I would like a method that can retrieve the `Foo` object, regardless of the name of the field. The logic would be "find the single ForeignKey that points to a `Foo` object, and get that object.

Is this possible?

Comment: can you not just specify a `@property` with a common name in all the classes ?

Comment: @karthikr: in practice, that will be hard, because the code will be written by different people working on different projects.

Comment: Then there is no way of achieving this AFAIK.

Comment: I agree with @karthikr. How about having a base class with a property that must be implemented that normalizes the name of the foreign key field? This way you could provide a contract for any classes that implement this field, raising an exception if that property isn't implemented.

Comment: @Brandon That was my initial thought, but then the OP would still have to go in and define the property to every class (note that the base class does not know the exact field names, which is not consistent across the board)

Comment: Yeah, the property would have to just point to fk field. Then you could call `my_model.foo` which is actually referring to the field `bar`...which doesn't smell great, but might not be too bad if properly documented.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two classes `FooBar` and `Foo`. `Foo` has a field `bar` that is a ForeignKey to `FooBar`. Then -

```
>>> print Foo.bar.field.rel.to
<class 'appname.models.FooBar'>
```

You can maybe write a method that iterates over all the properties of `Foo` and find the one that corresponds to `FooBar` model.